# Scaling an object ruins the keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

I animated a character preforming movements by using keyframes. I decided afterwards that I wanted to resize my scene; however, when I scaled my scene the keyframe values stayed the same. The character kept moving along the old path which does not work with the scale of the new scn

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain a little more about what you mean?  Did you select everything in your scene and scale?  When you edit your question it gets bumped back into active questions